# How do I use a standard class library in MVC6?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a reasonably convenient way to include a standard class library in MVC6? I thought the standard add reference dialog could create a wrapper but I'm not having any luck. Publishing it as a nuget package seems pretty inconvenient for ongoing development debugging.

If there isn't a wrapper is there a built in way to convert the standard class library to the new type?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have seen a couple of different approaches so far (using the `dnu` utility or adding references using VS). It is also slightly different depending if you want to reference an existing assembly or to reference a non asp 5 project within your solution.

**When you want to add a reference to an existing assembly that is not part of your solution:**

- **Use the `dnu wrap` command to add the reference**. You can open a developer command prompt and navigate to your solution folder or even easier just open the package manager console inside visual studio.

  Now if you want to add a reference to `fullPathToYourDll\Foo.dll` you will run the following command (where the framework argument is required when wrapping an assembly, and is defined as *Target framework of assembly to be wrapped*):

  ```
  dnu wrap "C:\fullPathToYourDll\Foo.dll" -f 4.5.1
  ```

  This will generate/update the **wrap** folder inside your asp 5 solution folder, including a file `mySolution\wrap\Foo\project.json` that looks like:

  ```
  {
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "frameworks": {
      "net451": {
        "bin": {
          "assembly": "../../../FooSln/Foo/bin/Debug/Foo.dll",
          "pdb": "../../../FooSln/Foo/bin/Debug/Foo.pdb"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  Finally, update the project.json file of your asp 5 to include a reference to your wrapped assembly as in:

  ```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Foo": "1.0.0-*",
      }
    }
  },
  ```
- **Alternatively, use VS**. Right click references in your ASP 5 project, select *Add Reference...* and then click on *Browse*. Now navigate to the folder containing the assembly and select the dll file.

  Visual studio will update for you the wrap folder (Creating the `mySolution\wrap\Foo\project.json`) and will even add the dependency in your project.json (The one in your asp 5 project).

**When you want to add a reference to a non asp 5 project within your solution:**

- **Use the `dnu wrap` command to add the reference**.

  The process is quite similar to the previous scenario of adding a reference to an existing assembly. Now if you want to add a reference to a non asp 5 project within your solution, you will run the following command:

  ```
  dnu wrap ".\myNonAsp5Project\MyNonAsp5Project.csproj"
  ```

  As when adding a reference to an existing assembly, this will generate/update the **wrap** folder inside your asp 5 solution folder, although this time the file `mySolution\wrap\MyNonAsp5Project\project.json` is slightly different since it is wrapping a project and not an assembly:

  ```
  {
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "frameworks": {
      "net451": {
        "wrappedProject": "../../MyNonAsp5Project/MyNonAsp5Project.csproj",
        "bin": {
          "assembly": "../../MyNonAsp5Project/obj/{configuration}/MyNonAsp5Project.dll",
          "pdb": "../../MyNonAsp5Project/obj/{configuration}/MyNonAsp5Project.pdb"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  Again, you will need to manually update the project.json file of your asp 5 to include a reference to your wrapped assembly as in:

  ```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "MyNonAsp5Project": "1.0.0-*",
      }
    }
  },
  ```
- **Alternatively, use VS**. Right click references in your ASP 5 project, select *Add Reference...*. Now expand *Projects* on the left hand side, select the project and click ok.

  Visual studio will update the wrap folder (Creating `mySolution\wrap\MyNonAsp5Project\project.json`) and will even add the dependency in your project.json (The one in your asp 5 project).

PS. I have been upgrading to Win10 and installing/uninstalling stuff as of lately and somehow I ended up with an environment variable *Platform=MCD*. This will be taken by MSBuild as the default platform and may give you some pain. Specifically, I was getting the error **Failed to resolve references** when running the `dnu wrap` command for wrapping a csproj file. (As [internally](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling/Commands/WrapCommand.cs) it uses msbuild to resolve the csproj references).

Comment: Amazingly detailed answer - Thank you very much!