# dnu wrap "Failed to resolve references" when trying to wrap .csproj based project for use from asp net 5 library

Tags: c#, reference, asp.net-core, csproj, dnu

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900713/how-do-i-use-a-standard-class-library-in-mvc6) excellent writedown of how to reference regular C# library projects in an asp.net 5 project, the DNU `wrap` command is the preferred way to do it.

Unfortunately `dnu wrap ".\Foo\Bar\MyProject.csproj"` does not work, and just outputs

```
Microsoft .NET Development Utility Clr-x86-1.0.0-beta8-15858

Failed to resolve references for D:\SomeFolder\Foo\Bar\MyProject.csproj
```

The project that should be wrapped is a regular class library. Target frameworks 4.5 and 4.6 have been tried, both produced the same error.

When trying to add a reference to the project in VS2015 using the Reference Manager, nothing happens. There is no error message, but no reference is added and no wrapper `project.json` is generated.

The Reference Manager seems to be overall not working for the (asp net 5 class library) project in question, which has `dotnet` specified as its framework target in the `project.json`. The **Assemblies** tab is empty, and **Browse...** gives a warning of `Project does not have target frameworks specified.`.

Comment: Does MyProject.csproj currently build?

Comment: Yes, it does. It is a pretty simple library, has only a handful of references itself. Some from System, 2 custom.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was found, the path to the nuget targets file in the (.csproj) project to be wrapped was incorrect. Apparently this had no detrimental effect on regularly building and using it, but prevented DNU from resolving the dependencies.