# ASP.Net 5 project referencing old class library

Tags: reference, asp.net-core, repository-pattern, asp.net-core-mvc, class-library

I was trying repository pattern with ASP.Net 5 project and service project. I referenced my "*.Service" class library project into my "*.Web" project but something went wrong with the reference. I removed all referenced to other libraries, even removed my "*.Service" and "*.Web" projects and added new empty ones but the newly created "*.Web" project still referencing the old version of deleted "*.Service" project.

"*.Web" > ASP.Net 5 project.
"*.Service" > .Net Framework 4.5.1 class library project.

[URL for project on github]
https://github.com/ahmedhelmy204/Publess/tree/master/Publess

[Screenshot of the current issue state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qjUx.png)

Comment: Your repository don't `Publess.Data` which you reference and includes `Publess.Core` on the wrong place (see [here](https://github.com/ahmedhelmy204/Publess/blob/master/Publess/wrap/Publess.Core/project.json#L7-L8) and compare with https://github.com/ahmedhelmy204/Publess/tree/master/Publess/artifacts/bin/Publess.Web). Moreover the `wrap` folder contains `EntityFramework.SqlServer` and `EntityFramework` which should be removed. Could you update your repository?

Comment: Thanks Oled, it worked after removing folders in wrap and rebuild.
Please post it in answers to mark as right answer.

Comment: Also I would appreciate if you added a link about wrap folder and it is work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your repository don't `Publess.Data`, which you reference and includes `Publess.Core` on the wrong place (see [here](https://github.com/ahmedhelmy204/Publess/blob/master/Publess/wrap/Publess.Core/project.json#L7-L8) and compare with [github.com/ahmedhelmy204/Publess/tree/master/Publess/artifacts/...](https://github.com/ahmedhelmy204/Publess/tree/master/Publess/artifacts/bin/Publess.Web)). Moreover the wrap folder contains `EntityFramework.SqlServer` and `EntityFramework`, **which should be removed**.

The directory `wrap/EntityFramework.SqlServer` for example contains `project.json` with wrong version number `1.0.0` for `EntityFramework` and it informs to get `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` from `.../Publess.Data/bin/Debug` folder

```json
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "bin": {
        "assembly": "../../Publess.Data/bin/Debug/EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `wrap` folder will be created when you add old project or old assembly to new ASP.NET 5 project. The entries `wrappedProject` and `bin` with `assembly` and `pdb` will be created.  One can use Visual Studio or `dnu wrap` to do this (see `dnu wrap -h`). See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31903691/315935), [the documentation](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file#bin-syntax-wrapping-a-dll) or [the post](http://forums.asp.net/t/2044755.aspx#5893070).

Some additional advices can gives you the source code of `dnu wrap`. See here and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/1.0.0-rc1-final/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling/Commands/WrapCommand.cs) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/1.0.0-rc1-final/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling/ConsoleCommands/WrapConsoleCommand.cs)