# Purpose of the 'wrap' folder in ASP.NET 5 (Core 1.0) projects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have ASP.NET 5 (or Core 1.0) project in solution and I tried to add reference in this project to some .NET Framework 4.5 projects. After adding reference in my solution folder a new folder 'wrap' is created.

This folder then makes some issues with references and packages versions. More in [Referencing class library in ASP.NET 5 - dependency issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160129/referencing-class-library-in-asp-net-5-dependency-issues)

What is this folder 'wrap' for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose is to enable library sharing between the 'old' csproj files and the new xproj. My take on why this is done as it is, is that this makes sure that, as the eco system moves forward and in a couple of years we've all happily forgotten about csproj dependencies, we have no remnants of supporting this in our own projects.

Comment: thanks. but I have a lot of problems with this folder because of different versions project.json and I had to remove almost all folders from 'wrap' folder. Do you have some problems? More info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160129/referencing-class-library-in-asp-net-5-dependency-issues

Comment: Sure, the technology isn't totally sorted yet. I've encountered quite a couple of problems with it, but have also found they've generally been easy to fix, except of the Newtonsoft one (which I had as well). Normally I fix it by removing the referenced project from the references of the asp.net project, remove the wrap folder of it and re-reference it. Hope it helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this wrap folder is no longer necessary. I

1. create an ASP.NET Core empty web project,
2. create a new csproj project, and
3. simply right click on .NET Core's Reference node. It no longer creates the wrap folder.

[image: Right click on Reference]

I remember the RC version of .NET Core used to create the wrap folder. This is no longer the case.

I am using VS2015 Update 3, ASP.NET and Web Tool 2015.1 14.1.211111.0, and Net Core SDK 1.0.0-preview2-003131