# Add reference to a class library with Asp.Net MVC 6 (dnx451)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I try to add a reference to a class library in my Asp.net mvc 6 project.
My library is MyClassLibraryExample and it is compiled with the good Framework 4.5.1

In my project.json, I have :

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "MyClassLibraryExample": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    }
  }
```

But it doesn't work, my class library is wrapped correctly in my solution but the reference in my dns451 does not work better !
I tied the two methods to wrap :
- "Add reference" link
- "dnu wrap" command

My error :

> Errors in D:\Dev\TFS\team2\Cactus\CactusV3\Cactus.WebMvc6\project.json
>       Unable to locate Dependency MyClassLibraryExample >= 1.0.0-*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use a standard class library in MVC6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900713/how-do-i-use-a-standard-class-library-in-mvc6)

Comment: Thanks. I tried the two methods : I wrapped with success my class library, and then update dependencies for dnx451 framework...  but it doesn't work better.