# Use regular portable libraries in .Net Core RC2

Tags: c#, portable-class-library, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

I have a C# project that relegates code to Portable Libraries projects, so they can be reused in .Net and Silverlight environments seamlessly.

The PCLs target `.Net45` and `Silverlight 5`.

Now I want to use the same PCLs in .Net Core environment. If possible, I want to keep my solution with .Net and Silverlight environments and reuse the Portable projects in a new .Net Core solution.

When I try to add a reference to a regular PCL project from a .Net Core Library, it fails to read the dependency.

> NU1001 The dependency could not be resolved.

If I attempt to add a reference to the PCL assembly I get an error:

> .NET Core projects only support referencing .NET framework assemblies in this release. To reference other assemblies, they need to be included in a NuGet package and reference that package.

Is it possible to use regular PCLs on .Net Core environment? Or I need to create new .Net Core libraries?

If I need to create new projects, how can I avoid duplicated code?

Comment: It is possible to use PCLs in a .NET Core project using the `import` keyword (see [docs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#portable-profiles)). The easiest way to test this would be to create a Nuget package of your PCL library and attempt to reference it in `project.json`.

Comment: Thanks @NateBarbettini, but I'm already targeting the same PCL moniker and doesn't allow me to reference a PCL project, importing the same moniker would be pointless, doesn't it?. Creating a NuGet package would remove the reference to the projects itself.

Comment: I has the same problem. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900713/how-do-i-use-a-standard-class-library-in-mvc6) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to add reference
2. Browse the project which you want to refer.
3. Select the .dll of the project instead of the project itself.
4. Add .dll reference and build.

Comment: Thanks, but when I attempt to do that in a .Net Core project I get the error described in the post `.NET Core projects only support referencing .NET framework assemblies in this release...`

Comment: Then i think you need to migrate your PCL project in .net core first and then use the it in your .net core project.

Comment: Yes, I agree, that would work, the only problem is that I'll miss a few features present en `.csproj` that aren't available in `project.json` as custom tools for resource files and file linking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/da-dk/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-webapi/). Here you can make an API of version 4.5.2 and call that API in your .net core project. That API will work as a bridge in your old class library and .net core application. the hosting of your class library will become separate. I think this will work in your case.